# Flagging a question to be closed as off-topic should offer more options

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently, when you flag a question as off-topic, you cannot specify which other SE website it should belong to. I think we should at least have the option to specify that it can belong to Data Science SE, Stack Overflow and Stats SE, given that these three websites are quite related to our AI SE website.

Comment: Beta sites can't have migration paths (and can't be the target of migration). Use custom flag instead if the question really deserves to be migrated (as the golden rule is: don't migrate crap).